# "RuntimeError: fdopen() failed unexpectedly" when reading too many gml files

Tags: python, igraph

I am reading too many GML files (few thousands) using igraph with python.
At some point of running the code, I got the following run time error:

```
RuntimeError: fdopen() failed unexpectedly
```

I spent a lot of time trying to understand the causes, but I did not find any thing helpful.

The root cause was produced from the code here https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/blob/master/src/filehandle.c#L231

The code I used is bellow. It breaks at the line of reading the GML after reading only few hundreds of the files.

```
gmls= []
for f in sorted(glob.glob('path_to_gmls'), key=os.path.getsize):
    g = Graph.Read_GML(f)
    gmls.append(g)
```

UPDATE:
I tried the same code on Mac, and it works just fine. The problems is on Windows.

UPDATE2:
I tested the package using the following code, and it runs without problems.

```
import igraph.test
igraph.test.run_tests()
```

Comment: What happens if you run this, eg. from a REPL prompt? `list(sorted(glob.glob('path_to_gmls'), key=os.path.getsize))`

Comment: Ok just read your comment about it failing after 1029 files: I suspect it could have to do with the file descriptor never being closed for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Are you running out of memory?  (I'm not a python programmer).  If multiple files are being opened at the same time then the buffers for those open handles might be taking up a considerable amount of memory. Also, it appears that you are appending the contents of the file to an in-memory array.  If the contents are large again it could be a memory issue.

Comment: It is very unlikely that the problem is the memory. I used way larger files under the same environment with no problems.

Comment: Another thing to explore.  File path size.  Windows used to have a 255 character limit on file path sizes.  Some APIs (depending on the language) and also perhaps depending on the use of a UNC style path vs. the traditional c:\...., still are limited to 255 characters in some situations.  If your path to the files is somewhat deep a longer named file might push it over the edge.

Comment: I've never though of that. However, i checked it, and did not work too!